# Docker Swarm Constrain Shared Host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Is it possible to use labels to force two services onto the same host, but not constrain to only 1 host.  The compose below will put them both on the same host, but I lose the value of the swarm to redeploy if something goes wrong.

```
service1:
  deploy:
  placement: 
    constraints: 
        - node.hostname == worker1  
service2:
  deploy:
  placement: 
    constraints: 
        - node.hostname == worker1
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why must they run on the same host? That seems like a swarm anti-pattern.

Comment: They don't *have* to run on the same host, but due to communication and network latency they perform better on the same host.
I'm trying to take an application designed to run 4 services on one host using docker-compose up and improve the reliability.

Answer (score 0):

A node label constraint would not work if multiple hosts had that label. Placement preferences would not work either, since the only option, spread, is the opposite of what you want. In fact, swarm prefers to place services on different hosts to make the application more resilient. Your requirement does not seem well-suited to swarm mode.